# How can I find the percentage of men and women in a certain building?

Tags: mysql, statistics

Tables:

```
- Activities: id, userId, description, buildingId
- Buildings: id, name
- User: id, name, gender
```

Users can create activities for example: "checking mail" would be an activity, the buildingid links to a building where a certant activity is going on.

What I need is a query that will get the % male/female per building, based of the amount of activities going on at such building.

For example:

```
User: 1, mike
Building: 1, main hall

Activities:

id: 1
userId: 1 (mike)
description: "checking mail"
buildingId: 1 (main hall)

id: 2
userId: 1 (mike)
description: "getting coffee"
buildingId: 1 (main hall)
```

So I want to get the % female / male of the building 1 (main hall) how can I do this the best way?

Comment: Seems like schoolwork, what did you try yourself..?

Comment: Im very bad in Mysql, seriously, im sorry.

Comment: Did you try to find some pen-and-paper solution? That would be a good start to "translate" it into some SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT buildingId, 
  (SUM(CASE WHEN `User`.gender='male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/
  COUNT(*))*100 as male_percent
FROM Activities JOIN `User` ON Activities.userID=`User`.id 
GROUP BY `Activities`.buildingId
```

Or if you prefer ratio:

```
SELECT buildingId, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN `User`.gender='male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/
  SUM(CASE WHEN `User`.gender='female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ratio
FROM Activities JOIN `User` ON Activities.userID=`User`.id 
GROUP BY `Activities`.buildingId
```